# Is it possible to power bio-chips with blood sugar?

Tags: biomedical-engineering

Suppose I want to implant a bio-chip that consumes a lot of power into my body, for example, a full-fledged CPU, and I don't want to lug around a heavy battery like the ones used in pacemakers, is it possible to be in Rome and do as the Romans do, i.e. draw and utilize the sugar inside my blood as fuel, like a huge living and breathing body cell or an organ like the liver? Let's assume I can put this device where there's a lot of blood flow, say the jugular vein.

Comment: How will you turn the sugar into energy? Better on the Biology Stack?

Comment: @SolarMike Metabolize it exactly the same way as body cells. Come on, if I could casually think of it, somebody must've come up with exactly the same idea.

Comment: So, next step is how will the device then get rid of the waste products?

Comment: @SolarMike My last biology lesson is about 10 years ago, but I seem to recall this structure called mitochondrion in all body cells that has a large number of complex enzymes embedded on a film that breaks down glucose and produces ATP. A cell simply receives glucose and releases CO2 and H2O through simple diffusion. So there's no complicated waste disposal.

Comment: So how is your "not complicated" CO2 and H20 waste disposal process going to operate on this chip - just leave it free in the body? will that cause a bulge?

Comment: @SolarMike By having something of a bio-chip. Like a huge, oversized mitochondrion that has a single highly folded membrane having exactly the same enzymes on it that powers some proton pumps that forms a large number of tiny batteries that provides ~1.5V and 5~10W of power that powers a separate low-power computer chip. Somehow trigger a growth signal that has it completely surrounded by veins like the tangles of veins commonly found in cancer tumors thereby having a good volume-to-surface area ratio, facilitating fast enough diffusion.

Comment: What "heavy batteries used in pacemakers" are you talking about? Modern ones weigh about 1 ounce, last 7 or 8 years, and are implanted along with the pacemaker itself, so you don't have to "lug about" anything at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to do this *could* be a [microbial fuel cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_fuel_cell#Power_generation).

This has, apparently, been tested  ex-vivo: [A pacemaker powered by an implantable biofuel cell operating under conditions mimicking the human blood circulatory system - battery not included](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236071090_A_pacemaker_powered_by_an_implantable_biofuel_cell_operating_under_conditions_mimicking_the_human_blood_circulatory_system_-_battery_not_included)

Another approach, which also works at least ex-vivo, is called Abiotic Biofuel Cell: [Pacemaker Activated by an Abiotic Biofuel Cell Operated in Human Serum Solution](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/elan.201400440)

Keywords here are biofuel cell and microbial fuel cells, knowing these you can google the rest yourself.